# Delete row indices based on common columns in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isin

I have following two dataframes df1 and df2

```
  final  raw  st
   abc   12  10
   abc   17  15
   abc   14  17
```

and

```
   final   raw
    abc   12
    abc   14
```

My expected output is

```
  final  raw  st
   abc   17  15
```

I would like to delete rows based on common column value.
My try:
`df1.isin(df2)`
This is giving me Boolean result. Another thing, I tried
`df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['final', 'raw'], how = 'inner')` so that we get all the common columns for `df1` and `df3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closed with `merge` you just need extra step. First you need to perform an outer join to keep all rows from both dataframes and enable `indicator` of `merge` then filter on this indicator to keep right values (from `df2`). Finally, keep only columns from `df1`:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['final', 'raw'], how='outer', indicator=True) \
        .query("_merge == 'left_only'")[df1.columns]
print(df3)

# Output
  final  raw  st
1   abc   17  15
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the correct column when using `isin`.

```
result = df1[~df1['raw'].isin(df2['raw'])]
```